# Robolectric: Testing that a cancel on dialog did not start new activity

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am starting unit testing with Robolectric. I have a button which when clicked will popup an confirmation dialog to the user. When the user clicks on `BUTTON_POSITIVE`,  a new activity is started, a click on BUTTON_NEGATIVE, nothing happens, user stays on the current activity.

For BUTTON_POSITIVE use case, I was able to test the following way:

```
    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
    assertThat(currentActivity, new StartedMatcher(NextActivity.class));
```

For BUTTON_NEGATIVE use case, I am not sure as what to assert for:

```
    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).performClick();
    //What should I assert next to check I am still in currentActivity?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try:

```
ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Robolectric.shadowOf( activity );
assertNull( shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity() );
```